# Change URL of the Web Part Close-Button

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

I  got a `StartSite.aspx`. I have some Web Parts on that site (news feed).

This web part - Template has a "Close" Button.

After closing an object, I navigate to `AllItems.aspx`

Isn't it possible to change the url of the button to the mainsite? (`StartSite.aspx`)

Comment: Please set default page and also check button type="button"

Answer (score 0):

I'm new as well, but I've seen this issue pop up before.

You can try this:

**Step 1)** Hide the exising close button by adding a **Content Editor Web Part** to the `DispForm.aspx` Page

**Step 2)** Add the below style and *JavaScript* function to the `source editor` of the `Content Editor Web part`

```
<style>    
/*- hide the Exisiting close button -*/
.ms-ButtonHeightWidth
{
 display:none;
}    
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function redirectnews()
{
 window.location = "http://www.google.com"
}
</script>

<table>
<tr>
<td align="right">
<input type="button" value="Close" width="150"
onclick="redirectnews()">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If the above didn't work for you, try checking out this link, what you want to do is setup a URL redirect.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/5f20cc93-9bdd-4cec-9168-16a0a3f095f8